# Generate timestamp (unix format) with intervals

Tags: typescript, unix-timestamp

I'm quite new to TypeScript and I know it's built on top of JavaScript, but for some reason I keep getting errors so I'm kinda stuck.

I want to create a function that generates a timestamp with the unix format which has intervals of random numbers. For better explanation:

The starting timestamp should be `Date.now()`  which should give something like `1669111677979`.

The next step should be adding random numbers ranging from `60` to `120` on top of the `Date.now` for maybe 15 times.

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance!

I tried using for loops but that didn't quite solve my issue.

```
import { faker } from '@faker-js/faker';
import { IDeviceData } from '@backend/data';

export function generateFakeData(): IDeviceData {
  for(let interval = 0; interval < 15; interval+20){
    console.log(interval);
    }

  return {
    id: faker.datatype.uuid(),
    imei: faker.datatype.uuid(),
    sensorPayload: 'test',
    temperature: faker.datatype.number({ min: -40, max: 70 }),
    humidity: faker.datatype.number({ max: 100 }),
    carbondioxide: faker.datatype.number({ max: 1000000 }),
    timestamp: Date.now()+interval.toString()
  };
}
```

**UPDATE**

I did some more digging into the code and somewhere else it's generating data with a `for loop`. It runs the code 15 times and pushes it to the `devices` array.

```
const [devices, setDevices] = useState([] as IDeviceData[]);

useEffect(() => {
    if (environment.production === false) {
      const fakeData = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        fakeData.push(generateFakeData());
      }
      setDevices(fakeData);

    } else {...}
}
```

Now how can I make sure that the timestamp adds a few seconds on every push of code into the array?

Comment: Could you provide input and output examples of function you want to create? Should it be smth like `randomTimestamp()` which return random timestamp based on `Date.now()`? Don't understand why it is necessary to add random number 15 times

Comment: Why don't you post your code? "I keep getting errors" gives us no clue what is wrong.

Comment: I've added more context.

Answer (score 1):

You just need some sort of pseudorandom integer generation function. Here's an example:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/PQKhAIHEFMDtoE4EMAu1xPM2ATA9gLbgCWsaA5ouABSkDGANgK4DOxAbungGbgGnACSAB4BKcCGAAobk1h0UxPLHCUUAJSS5CASTI1+KgLzgADABo+I8CYCMogFzhYTAgCMqAbyngs0FEwIKgCyqAAWAHTcDHh4CNShKJHY+ATU4hDUQsLgALR8pOAA1OD24iWGANxSAL5SUgz+4CgsNuAAIqjQEbB4AO7p1XTKLCjNxATQo0gEAA4sTi7uiADaALpt69UycTSNY8RtppUk4AA8pQCsJ4dFduLevi3FJmqa2gR6KNQAbBalACZTKJqk8JlMUDN5hFZqwwtQWiDavVhrAWHhGhEYuQEeDpnMWCDwMBgBgEMgAJ7gHhXcAAIhShDpBQYDGILGgqJw40m+PmlmgSDoYXAf0AyAS2IF8VpIWZIBAoKRAA)

```ts
/** Generate a random integer (inclusive of min/max) */
function getRandomInt (min = 0, max = 1): number {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

let ts = Date.now();
const timestamps: number[] = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 15; i += 1) {
  ts += getRandomInt(60, 120);
  timestamps.push(ts);
}

console.log(timestamps); // array of 15 "random" millisecond timestamps, each 60–120 ms apart
```

Compiled JS from the TS playground:

```js
"use strict";
/** Generate a random integer (inclusive of min/max) */
function getRandomInt(min = 0, max = 1) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
let ts = Date.now();
const timestamps = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 15; i += 1) {
    ts += getRandomInt(60, 120);
    timestamps.push(ts);
}
console.log(timestamps); // array of 15 "random" millisecond timestamps, each 60–120 ms apart
```